# Problem when updating a value in multiple places on redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I would need your help please to update several data on redux, I have a products_services store which is composed of products and product group, I manage to update the products but I also need to update the products contained in my groups (in the group object -> Products: [{...}, {...}]). The problem is that my function returns me null instead of my two groups with the updated products .... I don't really understand why while I kept the same logic as to update a simple product .

Thank you in advance to those who will have the courage to read :)

```js
case "UPDATE_PRODUCT" :

            return {
                products_services: state.products_services.map(item => {
                    // if the item knows product_label it is a product
                    if (item.product_label) {
                        // if its id corresponds to the updated product
                        if (item.id === action.payload.id) {
                            // replace the old values
                            return Object.assign(item, action.payload)
                            //sinon retourne l'item
                        } else {
                            return item
                        }
                    // if the item is a group then you will check its products
                    } else if (item.group_name) {
                        item.Products.map((product) => {
                            // if in its products one contains the id then you replace it
                            if (product.id === action.payload.id) {
                                return Object.assign(product, action.payload);
                                // otherwise you return the old product
                            } else {
                                return product;
                            }
                        });
                    }

                }),

            }
```

*before update product in redux store :*
[image: before update product in redux store]

*after update product in redux store :*
[image: after update product in redux store :]

Comment: Try updating to `return item.Products.map((product) => {` as you currently not returning the mapped values in the `else if` block.

Comment: you put me on the track thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

In the `else if` block you are crurently returning the result of `item.Products.map((product)`:

```
return item.Products.map((product) => {
    // if in its products one contains the id then you replace it
    if (product.id === action.payload.id) {
        return Object.assign(product, action.payload);
        // otherwise you return the old product
    } else {
        return product;
    }
});
```

That being said, a nested `Array.prototype.map` would result in a nested array. It's not clear if that is what you are intending to do. If you want a flat array of products/items, you could consider using `Array.prototype.flatMap`:

```
return {
  products_services: state.products_services.flatMap((item) => {
    // if the item knows product_label it is a product
    if (item.product_label) {
      // if its id corresponds to the updated product
      if (item.id === action.payload.id) {
        // replace the old values
        return [Object.assign(item, action.payload)];
        //sinon retourne l'item
      } else {
        return [item];
      }
      // if the item is a group then you will check its products
    } else if (item.group_name) {
      item.Products.map((product) => {
        // if in its products one contains the id then you replace it
        if (product.id === action.payload.id) {
          return Object.assign(product, action.payload);
          // otherwise you return the old product
        } else {
          return product;
        }
      });
    }
  }),
};
```

Finally, there isn't any sort of `else` block so it could be possible neither of your conditions are being met. It would probably be good to add some sort of else/fallback logic.

Hopefully that helps!